# IDEA: create jar artifact from Android

Tags: jar, intellij-idea, apk

I am building an `Android` app, and I would like to repackage some of its classes as a `.jar` library.

I have tried the "build artifact" from `IDEA`, but I get a `jar` that also contains the unsigned `APK` and all the classes.

What is the correct way of generating a `Jar` file out of a folder of classes?
Do I need to create a separate project for the library classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to have a separate module with the library code and make your Android app depend on this module. Building artifact from this module output classes will not have any extra files.